# BrowserLink does not work for ASP.NET Core on Visual Studio 2017 RTM

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017, browser-link

I get the following error in the browser when I enable BrowserLink for my ASP.Net Core 1.1 application and I think because of that the BrowserLink does not work.

```
Browser Link: Exception thrown when trying to invoke Browser Link extension callback "microsoft.visualstudio.web.browserlink.sourcemappingextensionfactory.getCssMappingData":
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.Common.Helpers.VsWebUrlUtil.EnsureAbsoluteUrl(IVsHierarchy hierarchy, Uri& path)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.Common.Helpers.VsWebUrlUtil.GetSimpleVsWebUrlFromUrl(IVsHierarchy hierarchy, Uri url, ILocationContainer& container)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.Common.Helpers.VsWebUrlUtil.GetVsWebUrlFromUrl(IVsHierarchy hierarchy, Uri url)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.Common.Helpers.LazyLocationContainer.LazyLocationContainerFromUrl.CreateActualLocationContainer()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.Common.Helpers.LazyLocationContainer.GetPhysicalPath(Uri& physicalPath)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.Common.Helpers.DocumentLocation.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.Common.Helpers.IDocumentLocation.GetPhysicalPath(Uri& physicalPath)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.SourceMappingExtension.getCssMappingData(String cssUrl, String[] selectors)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.ClientMessaging.DispatchMessage(BrowserLinkConnection connection, MessageArgs obj)

Browser Link: Exception thrown when trying to invoke Browser Link extension callback "microsoft.visualstudio.web.browserlink.autosyncextensionfactory.trackCssDocuments":
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.Common.Helpers.VsWebUrlUtil.EnsureAbsoluteUrl(IVsHierarchy hierarchy, Uri& path)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.Common.Helpers.VsWebUrlUtil.GetSimpleVsWebUrlFromUrl(IVsHierarchy hierarchy, Uri url, ILocationContainer& container)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.Common.Helpers.VsWebUrlUtil.GetVsWebUrlFromUrl(IVsHierarchy hierarchy, Uri url)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.Common.Helpers.LazyLocationContainer.LazyLocationContainerFromUrl.CreateActualLocationContainer()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.Common.Helpers.LazyLocationContainer.GetPhysicalPath(Uri& physicalPath)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.Common.Helpers.DocumentLocation.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.Common.Helpers.IDocumentLocation.GetPhysicalPath(Uri& physicalPath)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.Common.Helpers.DocumentLocation.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.Common.Helpers.IDocumentLocation.get_PhysicalFileExists()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.AutoSyncExtension.trackCssDocuments(String[] trackHrefs, String[] untrackHrefs)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.ClientMessaging.DispatchMessage(BrowserLinkConnection connection, MessageArgs obj)

Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null
```

I have configured my App as follow:

.csproj config:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.4.337" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel" Version="2.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <Exec Command="bower install" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet bundle" />
</Target>
```

And in the Startup.cs file in Configure method I have called `app.UseBrowserLink();`.

**UPDATE**

It seems the error is related to the *.css files. If I remove all my CSS links I only get the following error:

```
Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null
```

Comment: I have the same problem. A temporary fix for me was to turn off Browserlink by removing `app.UseBrowserLink();` in my `Startup.cs` file. However a proper fix would be welcome...

Comment: I have opened an issue for this on github. https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/1015

Answer (score 2):

I landed on this thread first when searching for a fix for browser link in .NET Core with VS2017.

All I was missing was

```
app.UseBrowserLink();
```

in the Startup.cs `Configure` method.

See [Browser Link with ASP.NET Core v1.0 in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290047/browser-link-with-asp-net-core-v1-0-in-visual-studio-2015-update-3)

(This is probably better suited as a comment but I don't have enough rep.)

Comment: I think it's fine to post this as an answer personally.

Comment: @ivarni Given the error message cited, I just don't think this is the answer for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by removing the default browserlink package

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink

and installing

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader

This package was mentioned in this [guide from Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-browserlink). Not sure what the difference is but it seems to of solved my issues.