# Asp.net Core application is not running with VS 2017?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have installed the visual studio 2017 for ASP.Net Core. I created  Dot Net Core project. Build it successfully and run it but on Firefox it shows the blank page and on chrome it shows **"**The localhost page isn’t working**

**localhost is currently unable to handle this request"**

I thought there is a problem in code. I debugged the code and there is nothing wrong with the code. It's the default template and code generated for Asp.Net Core. I googled and tried many things like restart the VS, removed cache, etc but nothing worked for me. Then i uninstalled the VS 2017 and used **C Cleaner** to remove all temp files etc and installed the visual studio 2017 again but the same error came again. Then i created MVC application, console application in VS 2017 and both worked fine. Issue comes only in Asp.net core application. I use fiddler to see the request status and it is 500. I debugged the code but nothing wrong with the code(No Exception). I have tried many things but did not find anything helpful. Can anyone tell me what's the issue?

Comment: you can try to use command line for ASP.NET Core

Comment: You mean to use Kestrl? How would I debug then? I need IIS-Express to run using F5.

Comment: does it work with Ctrl-F5?

Comment: No it doesn't work with Ctrl+F5.

Comment: but it works with dotnet run?

Comment: Did you check what is the port is running into? Also, when you start the app, if running with IIS Express, should be a small icon under the task bar. Click there to see your app..

Comment: The port is http://localhost:31372/.  And app is running with IIS Express.

Comment: I would clean the solution, rebuild and then check are there any warnings? I would also keep an eye in the out in the output window.

Can you upload your solution to github or similar so that we can take a look at it?

Comment: Are you using fiddler? If the answer is yes so close it and see if it is help. Sometimes fiddler making problems with fire fox.

Answer (score 2):

The blank page response can be caused by a number of reasons. Sometimes because you are lacking something in the system , routing issues, wrong code on the wrong location, .csproj configuration issues, permission issues, and many more.

There are a couple of things you can try:

1. Check to see if you have the appropriate **ASP.NET Core Module** installed in you system. (Either x86 or x64 depending on your system )
2. Make sure you have enabled IIS Integration in your code
3. See if you have the [error middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/src/MusicStore/Startup.cs#L105) in your Configure code, it mostly helps to solve your issues by giving full detail.

Comment: Commenting app.usebrowserLink() solve the problem. I don't know what the issue but application is running fine. But i have application with angular 2 that i developed with Visual studio 2015 still have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are running into error similar to this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/1015) with browserlink .What version of browser link package do you have in your machine

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink should be 1.0.1 referring the [templates](https://github.com/aspnet/Templates/blob/dev/src/Templates.xml#L408)

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694973/browserlink-does-not-work-for-asp-net-core-on-visual-studio-2017-rtm) discuss the similar issue .If that does not solve, Please make sure you have 1.0.1 in your project referenced  and then try this

- Clearing your NuGet cache
   `dotnet nuget locals all --clear`
- Set Environment variable DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE to 1 . This is to avoid caching packages
- `dotnet restore`

Answer (score 0):

Does it happens to be runtime compilation issues?

I stumble across this issues log while studying the feasibility of using ASP.Net Core for ERP System host on LinuxOS.

[Issues #2017 on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2017)

Try setting

`<PreserveCompilationContext>false<PreserveCompilationContext>`

in your csproj