# could not run the ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

[image]

when i run the ASP.NET Core MVC application from Visual studio 2022, it getting conflicts with source and module file(please refer the attached image.)
We are migrating MVC5 project to ASP.NET Core MVC and i dont know these initial configuration settings

Pls assist me on this
Thanks

I need to run the application in the browser.

Comment: Delete the `Bin folder` and rebuild your project, it would resolve your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the source file is different from when the module was built](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087390/the-source-file-is-different-from-when-the-module-was-built)

Comment: @Peter B  after delete the the content inside the bin and obj folder I got diiferent error. Unable to start the program. 'D:\Krishnapandi\ADS_localbranch\PDSAPP-CORE\PDSAPP\bin\Debug\net6.0\PDSAPP.exe'. The system cannot find the file specified. Help me what to do next pls .

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610220/asp-net-core-application-is-not-running-with-vs-2017

Answer (score 0):

Please delete the **bin** folder and **rebuild** your project.

Comment: Thnaks for ur support. after delete the the content inside the bin and obj folder I got diiferent error.
Unable to start the program.
'D:\Krishnapandi\ADS_localbranch\PDSAPP-CORE\PDSAPP\bin\Debug\net6.0\PDSAPP.exe'.

The system cannot find the file specified.

Help me what to do next pls .

Comment: Did you rebuild the project??

Comment: Yes, I cleaned and Rebuild the project. The dll and exe files is not generating when rebuild the project